# 3502i no console output, how to properly diagnose?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, access-point

I have purchased an old cisco 3502i AP from good old ebay.  I'm trying to set it up, but am not receiving anything over a console connection.  I'm using the exact same USB adapter & console cable that I used to successfully set up my 1841 router.  I set up the data bits, parity, stop bit, and flow control settings as specified by cisco as well as many other questions on this site; and I have tried every baud rate I've found out there.

I've hard reset the router to the best of my headless state; 30 second hold of the mode button.  The LED is blinking green, red, then pausing before a repeat.  Unfortunately given the fact that I bought this on ebay, I have absolutely no idea what ios this is running, if any.

Spamming keys at a console no matter the baud rate, always generate `▒` characters, and during power up, nothing is outputted to the console at all.  Also given my state, I don't have an account capable of downloading an official cisco IOS.

What are my next steps?  It seems as though the IOS is either corrupt or something?  Again I could connect to a 3500 switch and an 1841 router with no issues, same console hardware.  If it matters, the AP is connected to the switch, with dhcp managed by the 1841.  Any help or pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it helps anything or anyone, for all Cisco devices console setup is: Baud: 9600, Data: 8 bit, Parity: none, Stop bits: 1 bit and no flow control.

Comment: Yep, used this with several different terminal emulators, all to no avail.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: None of them have resolved the issue, there must be an IOS issue, that's all I can guess at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The LED blinking pattern indicates the [AP is in discovery mode](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/3500/quick/guide/ap3500getstart.html#pgfId-37791), so it sounds like the IOS image is valid.  I suspect either your baud rate isn't right, or there's a problem with the console interface.  You could set up a DHCPserver and see if it gets an address.  Then you might be able to telnet to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try all the possible baud rates one-at-a-time

4800
9600
19200
38400
57600
115200